# How to get an object's rotation to match the player's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Unity game where you can use your imagination to summon things. The first thing you get is a cannon, but I'm having trouble making the cannon look at where the player is looking. I just need to change the z rotation to match the players but for some reason when I do this it changes the x rotation to be 180. Here's my code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        Vector3 playerPos = transform.position;
        Vector3 playerDirection = transform.forward;
        Quaternion playerRotation = transform.rotation;
        float spawnDistance = 10;

        smoke.transform.position = playerPos + playerDirection * spawnDistance;
        smoke.Play();
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCannon(1));

        IEnumerator SpawnCannon(float waitTime)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            cannon.transform.position = smoke.transform.position;
            cannon.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(-90,0,playerDirection.z,0);
        }
        
      
    }
```

Comment: a) **`Quaternion` != Euler angles** ... the four components of a `Quaternion` move between `-1` and `1` and can not simply be used like Euler angles ... so of something it should probably be `cannon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,playerDirection.z);` .. **BUT** b) `transform.forward` returns a normalized `Vector3` with a **direction** which is not a rotation ... and c) what you see in the Inspector is the **local** rotation relative to the parent in Euler representation .. what speaks against `cannon.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;` ?

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Now I think I can solve the problem on my own.

Answer (score 0):

does the cannon have a rigidbody? If it does then freeze the rotation of the canon on the x axis. But if it doesn't have a rigidbody, add one and freeze the rotation of the canon on the x axis. and this line of code here: `Quaternion playerRotation = transform.rotation;`, you can replace it with this : `Quaternion playerRotation = transform.rotation.[AXIS HERE];`. Replace the [AXIS HERE] with the axis you want the canon to rotate in, if you want the canon to be rotating in the z axis, you would replace [AXIS HERE] with z. Hope this helps a little! :D

Comment: That's a smart way of doing it. But instead of that I just set the cannons forward vector to the players forward vector.